# Trying to send email, getting error saying "this import java.mail" cannot be resolved

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a simple program to send out mail using the eclipse ide, buy I cannot import the librarie for mail.
On the line saying
import javax.mail.*;

I get a error saying

```
"this import java.mail" cannot be resolved"
```

The code is from
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

public class SendEmail
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {    
      // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
      String to = "abcd@gmail.com";

      // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
      String from = "web@gmail.com";

      // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
      String host = "localhost";

      // Get system properties
      Properties properties = System.getProperties();

      // Setup mail server
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

      // Get the default Session object.
      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

      try{
         // Create a default MimeMessage object.
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

         // Set From: header field of the header.
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

         // Set To: header field of the header.
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                  new InternetAddress(to));

         // Set Subject: header field
         message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

         // Now set the actual message
         message.setText("This is actual message");

         // Send message
         Transport.send(message);
         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
      }catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
```

Comment: "this import java.mail". It doesn't say that. Look again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaMail does not ship with Java SE. You can download it from Oracle, [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html).